# Add to array from json and execute data in template

Tags: templates, go, render

I have a little qiestion!

How add to array data from json and execute template. Simple. But Not working!

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "os"
    "encoding/json"
)

type Person struct {
    Name   string
    Jobs   []*Job
}

type Job struct {
    Employer string
    Role     string
}

const templ = `The name is {{.Name}}.

{{with .Jobs}}
    {{range .}}
        An employer is {{.Employer}}
        and the role is {{.Role}}
    {{end}}
{{end}}
`

func main() {
    job1 := Job{Employer: "Monash", Role: "Honorary"}
    job2 := Job{Employer: "Box Hill", Role: "Head of HE"}

    byt := []byte(`{"num":6.13,"Jobs":[{"Employer": "test1", "Role": "test1"},{"Employer": "test2", "Role": "test2"}]}`)

    var dat map[string]interface{}

    if err := json.Unmarshal(byt, &dat); err != nil {
             panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(dat)




    // HOW ADD FROM ARRAY 'dat' TO STRUCT 'Job'
    // LINE 54




    person := Person{
        Name:   "jan",
        Jobs:   []*Job{&job1, &job2},
    }

    t := template.New("Person template")
    t, err := t.Parse(templ)
    checkError(err)

    err = t.Execute(os.Stdout, person)
    checkError(err)
}





func checkError(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Fatal error ", err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```

Here you can play/test code: http://play.golang.org/p/AB8hGLrLRy

Watch line 46.

Thank you very much!

Comment: This? http://play.golang.org/p/EZJt-y-mMJ

Comment: Great! This is what i want! Thank you VERY MUCH!
Little question little bit ;)

Comment: Great! This is what i want! Thank you VERY MUCH!
Little question little bit ;)

When i read json from file. If i print json file: `[{test1 test1}]`
Ok, convert to byte:
`byt := []byte(config.Social)`
it types this:
`cannot convert config.Social (type []struct { Employer string "json:\"url\""; Title string "json:\"Role\"" }) to type []byte`

Comment: What you want to acheive? You want to marshall your structure to byte array? Please provide an example

Comment: https://gist.github.com/liamka/e25ef01d6e8736066769
Here!

Comment: If I understand you correct, you don't need to use unmarshall on your 'config'. Just copy values from your config. I can't provide answer right now, I am driving now. I will help later

Comment: Thanks! I look forward! Drive safety!

Comment: Sorry, I was out from my computer. Try this https://play.golang.org/p/YoWER5AKNK

Answer (score 0):

First thing, your `dat` var isn't of the right type. You should have something like that:

```
dat := struct {
    Jobs []*Job
}
```

That way, when unmarshalling your JSON string into `dat`, the `Jobs` key will be filled with a array of `*Job` initialized with your data's array.
I'm using an anonymous struct, but you could also have a named struct (see @RoninDev's comment for an example).

Then, just add them to the person array, something like that:

```
person.Jobs = append(person.Jobs, jobs.Jobs...)
```

Note the `...` operator, which use an array as a variadic argument.

You can see the full working code on this <kbd>[playground](http://play.golang.org/p/eCRM2u_pCN)</kbd>.

Comment: That still isn't an entirely accurate representation of his data.

Comment: Its sufficient, and he doesn't use the remaining attribute.

Comment: Yeah that's true, the other property isn't needed. I think it's worth detailing though because OP's problem is arising from not understanding the structure of the json and/or how it is modeled in Go.

Answer (score 0):

You're unmarshalling the json fine, it's just into the most ambiguous type the language offers... You could unbox it with a series of type asserts but I don't recommend it. The json can easily be modeled in Go with a structure like the following;

```
type Wrapper struct {
    Num float64 `json:"num"`
    Jobs []*Job  `json:"Jobs"`
}
```

Here's an updated example of your code using that struct; http://play.golang.org/p/aNLK_Uk2km

After you've deserialized them you can just use `append` to add them to the jobs array in the person object like `person.Jobs = append(person.Jobs, dat.Jobs...)`

Comment: I think that `jobs := dat["Jobs"].([]Job)` would fail, as unmarshalling of `interface{}` to `[]type` isn't a single operatin…

Comment: @Elwinar yeah that's true, it's actually a lot more work to unbox that data.